# How to get the value of allDay in fullcalendar jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the fullcalendar jquery plugin and I want to get the value of allDay that is true or false and I want to append the value to a form.But value that is getting appended is [object Object]

```
<input type="hidden" id="apptAllDay" value="[object Object]">


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {

            $('#apptStartTime').val(start);
            $('#apptEndTime').val(end);          
            $('#apptAllDay').val(allDay);


            $.magnificPopup.open({
                  items: {
                    src: '#popup',
                    type: 'inline'
                  }
            });


        },
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        eventStartEditable : false,
        events: "http://localhost/app1/events",
    });



    $(document).on("click","#addEvent",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        doSubmit();
    });


    function doSubmit(){

        var title = $("#titleContainer").val();
        var description = $.trim($("#descContainer").val());
        var url = $("#urlContainer").val();

        if (!title) {
            alert("Title is required");
            return false;
        }

        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',
            {
                title: title,
                start: new Date($('#apptStartTime').val()),
                end: new Date($('#apptEndTime').val()),
                allDay: ($('#apptAllDay').val() == "true")
            },
        true);

       }

});
```

How can I get the real value that is TRUE or FAlSE?

Comment: very simple to debug, my advice is just use `console.log(allDay)`, it'll reveal to you properties that you want to append into that hidden input

Comment: I tried but couldn't understand anything!
here's a similar demo 
http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/selectable.html

can you help me out?

Comment: objects has properties. use what the `console.log` gave to you and access them thru `.` dot notation

Comment: I tried but there are 100s of properties.Can you use this and help?
http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/AzmJv/16/

Comment: just check out the right property that you actually need to use. i haven't used this plugin, just check out that property something like `$('#apptAllDay').val( (allDay.is_all_day) ? 'true' : 'false' );` by the way, check out the docs, might be related http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/allDayDefault/

Comment: proper docs link http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/

Answer (score 0):

This might probably help you, change according to your requirement.

```js
function parseClientEvents(){
    var clientArr = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    for(i in clientArr){
         console.log(clientArr[i]);//gives events full description.
         console.log(clientArr[i].allDay);
        //check for value here and append to your hidden field.
       //all your logic goes here.         
    }
    return true;
}
```